# The Text Is Not In Proper Position (Horizontal Menu)

Tags: html, css

I'm new here. I just wanted to ask about this problem.

The text inside horizontal menu isn't at the centre of the box and it looks weird. How do I make the text appear in a correct position? And how do I make the text inside horizontal menu into white? What did I do wrong in the coding? I don't see any problem in my coding. By the way, I use Dreamweaver to code this interface.

[image: Screenshot of The Preview]

HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Deane.co</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav1">
<h4><a href="index.html"><h1>Deane.co</a></h4>
<ul>
    <li id="active"><a href="index.html"></a>Home</li>
    <li><a href="products.html"></a>Products</li>
    <li><a href="register.php"></a>Registration</li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"></a>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="main-content">
<br>
<h1> Welcome To Deane.co </h1>
<br>
<p> Welcome to Deane.co the place to shop beautiful clothes easier </p>
<br>
<div id = "products">
<h4><a href="products.html">Check our products</a></h4>
</div>
</div>
<div id="shirtsaesthetic"> 
<div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
<h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
<p> RM40 </p>
</div>
<div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
<h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
<p> RM40 </p>
</div>
<div id="shirtsaesthetic1"> <img src="Images/shirtsaesthetic.jpg"> <br>
<h4> Hipster Blouse </h4> <br>
<p> RM40 </p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<h2>&copy; Allright Reserved</h2>
<div id="nav2">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
*{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#nav1 {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
line-height: 70px;
background: #a5aab1;
}
#nav1 h1 {
float: left;
font-size: 2.5em;
margin-left: 15px;

}
#nav1 h1 a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
#nav1 ul {
float: right;
margin-right: 15px;

}

#nav1 ul li {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}

#nav1 ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
padding: 25px;
}
#nav1 ul li:hover{
background: #bfc5ce;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.45s;

}
#active {
background: #bfc5ce;

}

#main-content {
width: 100&;
height: 600px;
background: url(Images/store-background3.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
color: black;
line-height: 40px;

}
#main-content a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
#products {
background: #a5aab1;
width: 170px;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
font-weight: 100;
}
#products:hover {
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 10px rgba(136, 131, 131, 0.83);
transition: all ease-in-out 0.45s;
}
#products a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;

}

#shirtsaesthetic {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background: white;
}
#shirtsaesthetic1 {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
padding: 5px;
display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 19px;
text-align: center;
}
#shirtsaesthetic1 img {
width: 300px;
height: 220px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: black;
}

#nav2 {

}

.header {
width: 30%;
margin: 50px auto 0px;
color: white;
background: #5F9EA0;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
border-bottom: none;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
padding: 20px;
}

form {
width: 30%;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #B0C4DE
background: white;
border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;

}
```

Comment: Try using `test-align :centre` on `#nav1 ul li`

Answer (score 1):

Your wrong code:

```
...
<div id="nav1">
<h4><a href="index.html"><h1>Deane.co</a></h4>
<ul>
    <li id="active"><a href="index.html"></a>Home</li>
    <li><a href="products.html"></a>Products</li>
    <li><a href="register.php"></a>Registration</li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"></a>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
...
```

Improved code:

```
...
<div id="nav1">
<h4><a href="index.html">Deane.co</a></h4>
<ul>
    <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.php">Registration</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
#nav1 ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your #nav ul code is currently floated to right side so it would be on the right part of the container

try this code instead

```
#nav ul{text-align:center !important;}
```

if that does not work on some circumstances or confilict on the code try this

```css
#nav ul{
  position:absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```